# Beaglebone Boot Fail with ALERT! PARTUUID does not exist

Tags: debian, u-boot, beagleboneblack

I have tried booting a Linux image in the eMMC through [u-boot](https://www.denx.de/wiki/U-Boot) but it always drops to the [busybox](https://busybox.net/) shell. As suggested by the busybox shell I double checked the PARTUUID (`8fb410a9-01`) using blkid, which matches; Why can't it load the [root file system](http://www.linfo.org/root_filesystem.html) ('rfs')?

My emmc has a single partition Debian image. U-boot lies in the first partition of my sd card(boot by pressing s2 switch. Here are my logs, uEnv.txt.

This standalone [Beaglebone](https://beagleboard.org/bone) boots just fine (without my u-boot and sd card not inserted). It boots fine from the emmc (which means emmc image is good) just when I try uboot from sd card this happens

```
ipaddr=192.168.7.2
serverip=192.168.7.1
console=ttyO0,115200n8
finduuid=part uuid mmc 1:1 uuid
netargs=setenv bootargs console=ttyO0,115200n8 root=UUID=aa9109fe-2099-47e0-b8a5-e1a3f87848b0 rootwait rw rootfstype=ext4 rootwait  coherent_pool=1M net.ifnames=0 quiet
loadaddr=0x82000000
ftdaddr=0x88000000
initramaddr=0x88080000
initrdsize=452040
netboot=echo Booting from emmc ...; setenv autoload no ;echo moving zimage from emmc to DRAM...;load mmc 1:1 ${loadaddr} /boot/vmlinuz-4.14.71-ti-r80;echo moving dtb from emmc to DRAM... ; load mmc 1:1 ${fdtaddr} /boot/dtbs/4.14.71-ti-r80/am335x-boneblack-uboot-univ.dtb ; echo moving initrd from emmc to DRAM...;load mmc 1:1 ${initramaddr}  /boot/initrd.img-4.14.71-ti-r80;echo running netargs ...; run netargs ; echo bootzzzz...;bootz ${loadaddr} ${initramaddr}:${initrdsize} ${ftdaddr}
uenvcmd=echo running netboot...;run netboot

Starting kernel ...
[    0.002066] timer_probe: no matching timers found
[    1.132460] wkup_m3_ipc 44e11324.wkup_m3_ipc: could not get rproc handle
[    1.444765] omap_voltage_late_init: Voltage driver support not added
[    1.452379] PM: Cannot get wkup_m3_ipc handle
Gave up waiting for root file system device.  Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
 - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
ALERT!  PARTUUID=8fb410a9-01 does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!


/dev/mmcblk1p1: LABEL="rootfs" UUID="aa9109fe-2099-47e0-b8a5-e1a3f87848b0" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="8fb410a9-01"


# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
/dev/mmcblk1p1  /  ext4  noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  1
debugfs  /sys/kernel/debug  debugfs  defaults  0  0
```

Comment: Are you trying to use PARTUUID deliberately or did that just happen by itself or what? PARTUUID is not supported in all contexts ( initramfs busybox findfs in particular does not support it, so it depends on initramfs implementation )

Comment: my Beagle Bone Black will not boot the SD card unless I'm pressing the button on the board above the SD card slot.

Comment: @frostschutz starting from 4.1.xx we need to pass the UUID of root file system partition as a kernel argument am i right ?. So if it is not supported what should be used in the Uboot to pass the rfs partition ?

Comment: @fcbsd I pressed the s2 switch on beaglebone or else the uboot would'nt have boot anyways as it lies in the sd card